Does int_leastX_t differ from intX_t?
int8_t, int16_t, int32_t, and int64_t are signed integer type with width of exactly 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively
with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values
(provided only if the implementation directly supports the type).
int_least8_t, int_least16_t, int_least32_t, and int_least64_t are smallest signed integer type with width of at least 8, 16, 32 and 64 bits respectively.
If an implementation has int8_t, then it looks like a natural choice for int_least8_t, as it is a type with width at least 8. However, for example on LLP64 data model both int and long are 32-bits, so int32_t could be int but int_least32_t could be long, which would be confusing, but is it valid?
Can I reasonably expect that int_least32_t (and char32_t) and int32_t will be the same type? Is there an actual implementation where int_leastX_t differs from intX_t? (except DeathStation 9000)

There are some architectures where word sizes are not powers of 2, and they don't have 8-bit bytes. They're not as common today, but when I was starting out I used machines with 36-bit words and 9-bit bytes, so there were no hardware types with 8, 16, or 32 bits.

But if intX_t exists, it seems reasonable to assume that int_leastX_t will be the same.

If both int and long are 32 bit integers, does it matter?

I have yet to see a valid case for the int_leastX_t types, I always use the fixed integer types.

@Schwern, as far as the language spec is concerned, yes it does matter.  Or at least, it can.  Even if (say) int and long have the same size and representation, they are still, formally, different types, and it still violates the strict aliasing rule to access a long via an lvalue of type int, or vice versa.  Such violations could lead to actual code failure in practice, perhaps because an implementation makes optimizations that would be invalid without the SAR violations.

@Marco that's because you've never worked on platforms with non-power-of-2 sizes. For example int32_t won't work in a 24-bit DSP but int_least32_t will


Can I reasonably expect that int_least32_t (and char32_t) and int32_t will be the same type?

Not char32_t, which is specified to be the same type as uint_least32_t. That is definitely not the same type as int32_t or int_least32_t.
You already made the case that if a conforming implementation defines int32_t, then that type is necessarily a candidate for int_least32_t, but that it is not necessarily the only candidate.  So is it reasonable to assume that all such implementations will define them to the same type?
If it is among your objectives to write strictly conforming code, or at least to minimize unnecessary assumptions, then of course not.  Otherwise, that's a matter of opinion.  Given that you're mindful in the first place that it can matter, and that you're thinking about portability, I would be inclined to guess that you're in the former camp.
I do think it's unlikely under those circumstances that an implementation would choose different types for int32_t and int_least32_t, but that's a different question.

Is there an actual implementation where int_leastX_t differs from intX_t?

I don't know of one, but I don't have any particular reason to suppose that there isn't one.  I am firmly in the minimizing assumptions camp, myself, so I pay no attention to the actual types underlying any of these standard typedefs, and I do not write code that depends on what those definitions are.
Even if there is no such implementation today, there might yet be one in the future.

This is kind of an artifact of C's signedness type system that allows exotic 1's complement and signed magnitude, as well as padding bits/bytes inside standard integer types.
C implementations from C99 to C23 must support int_least8_t to int_least64_t and their unsigned alternatives. Whereas it need not support int8_t to int64_t ("exact width integer types") if the underlying hardware does not support the corresponding integer type, or supports it but not in 2's complement/no padding format. (See C17 7.20.1.)
In theory some exotic computer which doesn't use two's complement or doesn't have 8 bit bytes should not implement int8_t etc at all. For example there still exist various DSPs that use 16 bit bytes. The correct implementation of standard C for such a target is to not support int8_t and make int_least8_t 16 bits.
The 2's complement part has been tweaked somewhat in upcoming C23, which dropped support for exotic signedness systems and requires 2's complement for all types (and not just for the intn_t types that were always guaranteed to be 2's complement):
C23 draft n3096 7.22.1.1, Exact-width integer types:

If an implementation provides standard or extended integer types with a particular width and no
padding bits, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.


There is no requirement that intn_t and int_leastn_t are compatible for a given n even if the specific integer type is supported. However, it would be mighty stange if they weren't on a mainstream 2's complement computer. I suppose if it makes anyone happier, you could block the code from compiling if that's not the case:
_Static_assert( _Generic((uint32_t){0}, uint_least32_t: 1, default: 0),
                "Weird compiler detected, get a better one." );


As a side-note, the reason why the INTN_C/UINTN_C boil down to int_leastn_t/uint_leastn_t is because these are guaranteed to supported. Even though in practice we probably rather use these macros together with intn_t/uintn_t.

As noted in another answer, the charn_t types are explicitly defined to be of the same type as the corresponding uint_leastn_t, so those are always compatible.

If there's still a live compiler for hardware with exotic signed-ness they're just going to ignore that line in the standard though. It's effectively dead letter.

@Joshua All of this crap is for the benefit of such an exotic implementation though, so why would it ignore that? I recall that certain DSP implementations did implement uint8_t even though they had no such type, which would render the compiler non-conforming. But anyone planning to write fully portable C between exotic DSPs and mainstream targets is clueless anyway, so I'm not sure how relevant that is. In my experience, DSP programmers are already reluctant to use C over asm anyway.

I am totally expecting any such live compiler that had int_least64_t as ones compliment to still have it as ones compliment and not change it. Some Cisco gear is still ones compliment and has a C compiler; though I'm not sure how much longer that special CPU will last.
